# how to draw line with animation?

Tags: iphone

I have implemented game application in which i want to draw line between two object.I have drawn line between two objects.But i want to draw with animation.can u advise me which animation i have to used between two points.

Edit:My excatly question is that:
Suppose there is two point like start point(100,100) and endpoint(300,300).I can draw line between this two point but i want to draw line with animation.I mean i can see line start from start point to end point with 2 secon duration.please help me about this question.

Answer (score 5):

+1 for Brad's answer—it'll work—but it looks like you can accomplish the same thing in a more straightforward fashion by animating the strokeStart and strokeEnd properties on CAPathLayer.

See http://oleb.net/blog/2010/12/animating-drawing-of-cgpath-with-cashapelayer/

Comment: Yeah, that was a handy addition in iOS 4.2. I need to go back and update some of these older answers with some of the extensions they've been adding over the last few versions.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to animate the extension of a line from point A to between points A and B, my recommendation would be to use a [CAShapeLayer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/index.html) for this.  CAShapeLayer lets you animate the interpolation between two paths with the same number of control points.  For an example of this in action, see [Joe Ricioppo's post on the subject](http://tumbljack.com/post/179975074/complex-interpolation-with-cashapelayer-free).

In your case, you'd start with a path that has two control points, both the same point, and use as the final path one that has a control point at the start of the line and one at the end.  The line will then animate out as if it were being drawn in a single brush stroke.