# How to draw line between two points with animation?

Tags: iphone

I have used the code below for drawing a line between two points.

```
#define PI 3.14159

CGContextBeginPath(ctx);

int x;
for(int y=rect.origin.y; y < rect.size.height; y++)
{
    x = ((rect.size.width/4) * sin(((y*4) % 360) * PI/180)) + rect.size.width/2;

    if(y == 0)
    {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, x, y);
    }
    else
    {
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, x, y);
    }
}

CGContextStrokePath(ctx);
```

But I want to implement this with animation. How would it be possible? Can you help me?

Comment: It must be morning since I fail to see how a SIN function helps you to draw a line at all.

Comment: If you're drawing a straight line, use a CALayer and set its geometry to be 1px wide, apply a border or background color to get it to render. If you're drawing a curved line, check out CAShapeLayer. Both can be animated.

Comment: Also, it looks like you have a lot of questions asked that have been answered but haven't marked any of them as answered. It helps with the  site to mark questions as answered when they are.

Comment: You just asked this same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1880035/how-to-draw-line-with-animation , to which I provided you one way of doing this.